passing "-e" as a parameter to awk is having unexpected results
I have short Bash script that will not pass "-e " to Awk:
str="Morgenstern"
ex = "-e "
for i in {1..11}
do
    echo $(echo $str| awk -v vv="$i" -v xx="$ex" 'print xx substr ($0,vv,1)}')
done
 

the results should be:
-e M
-e o
-e r

etc...
the actual result is
M
o
r

If I change ex to "-b " then I get the expected result (-b M, -b o, etc.)
I also tried hard coding "-e " in the Awk statement with the same bad result.
How do I get Awk to accept "-e " as a parameter or as a literal?

Please fix your example to be runnable (no spaces around =, missing {) and minimal.

See also useless use of echo

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag and didn't provide a syntactically valid shell script or awk script.

Whatever it is you're trying to do, a shell loop to call echo on the output of executing a subprocess to call a second echo piped to awk passed a variable containing a string to be printed from awk to be passed back to the surrounding first echo is not the way to do it. Create a question with a [mcve] about whatever it is you're trying to do (as opposed to how you're trying to do it) so we can help you.

You don't need awk at all here. You can iterate over the characters of str directly in bash.

The issue is the redundant echo, which through $(…) is being passed two arguments and one it recognizes as an option:
echo -e M

Remove the redundant echo, and avoid the same problem with the other one by using printf.
str="Morgenstern"
ex="-e "
for i in {1..11}
do
    printf %s "$str" | awk -v vv="$i" -v xx="$ex" '{ print xx substr($0, vv, 1) }'
done

Also, awk has for loops.
str="Morgenstern"
ex="-e "
printf %s "$str" | awk -v xx="$ex" '{
    for (i = 1; i <= length($0); i++) {
        print xx substr($0, i, 1)
    }
}'


Depending on which echo you have, echo -- -e might also work; but generally prefer printf anyway.

Using the awk loop has the added advantage of being faster than the for loop I was using.

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way
str="Morgenstern"
ex="-e "
echo "$str" | awk -v x="$ex" '{print gensub(/(.)/, x"\\1\n", "g", $0)}'

gives output
-e M
-e o
-e r
-e g
-e e
-e n
-e s
-e t
-e e
-e r
-e n

Explanation: I store ex content in x variable, then use gensub string function to change every character (.) by prepending content of x and appending newline.
Disclaimer this solution assumes ex is not holding any character or sequence thereof of special meaning to gensub's 2nd argument (e.g. &), if this is not case ignore this answer entirely
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Superfluous regex grouping in Daweo's solution — this suffices :
str="Morgenstern"
ex="-e "
echo "$str" | gawk -v x="$ex" '{ print gensub(/./, x"&\n", "g") }'


-e M
-e o
-e r
-e g
-e e
-e n
-e s
-e t
-e e
-e r
-e n

At the same time, extra grouping needs to account for more than just &, as both \\0 and \\1 apply to the scenario with just 1 capture group :
ex='-e \\0\\1'
echo "$str" | gawk -v x="$ex" '{print gensub(/(.)/, x"\\1\n", "g") }' 


-e MMM
-e ooo
-e rrr
-e ggg
-e eee
-e nnn
-e sss
-e ttt
-e eee
-e rrr
-e nnn

A cleaner solution would be to regex escape x somewhere in the BEGIN { } section, or go with vanilla gsub() unless one needs complex capturing group logic.
gsub() still requires a bit of regex escaping, but not as messy as the one for gensub().
